# Display shipping price and shipping VAT in woocommerce pdf invoice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, invoice

I want to change code for my custom template of Woocommerce PDF invoices & packing slips plugin.

Now invoice shows just shipping price as:
Shipping: €6.05 via flat rate

I need it to show shipping price and included VAT amount:
Shipping: €6.05 via flat rate (includes €1.34 VAT)

the original code is:

```
<tfoot>
        <tr class="no-borders">
            <td class="no-borders" colspan="6">
                <table class="totals">
                    <tfoot>
                        <?php foreach ( $this->get_woocommerce_totals() as $key => $total ) : ?>
                            <tr class="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                                <th class="description"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                                <td class="price"><span class="totals-price"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></span></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

I tried changing it, but with my limited knowledge i had no luck.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmOhz.png)

Comment: There is an extension for that: https://wpovernight.com/downloads/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips-premium-templates/

Comment: https://docs.wpovernight.com/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/displaying-taxes/